# Intent.getData() return null on Android API 23

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

`Intent.getData()` return `null` on Android API 23 and work fine for previous version ?

```
private void takePicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

...

```
private void choosePicture()
{
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
}
```

...

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ...
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String imagePath = getPath(selectedImage);
    dest = new File(imagePath);
    decodeFile(imagePath);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can it have anything to do with runtime permissions in 6.0?

Comment: does are the granted permission : `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` `Manifest.permission.CAMERA`

Comment: @Vucko is write external storage missing :/ ?

Comment: That does not matter, adding them in the manifest is one thing, asking them at runtime is another. Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) and see if adding permissions at runtime fixes it. API level 23+ requires this.

Comment: There is no intent.getData() in your code. Please post the code you are complaining about.

Comment: @greenapps check the edit

Comment: anybody have answer for this question i m in trouble my code is working properly on every device except lollipop and marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean ifPermissionReady(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            System.out.println("req camera permission*****");
            checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Constant.PERMISSION_CAMERA);
            return false;
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            System.out.println("req write storage permission*****");
            checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Constant.PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Try call this function first. make sure you get permission. API23 requires this.  Run it when you click to enable camera for taking photo. Are you able to launch camera without this function. My app will crash if i don't do this in API 23

Answer (score 0):

If `data.getData()` returns null then try:

```
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```